# Download a file directly to filesystem in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, wget

Is there a way to **stream a file directly** to the filesystem? Even if the connection is lost, I want to see all contents in that specific file in the fs. Just like wget or curl.

However, using request leads to the issue of first downloading the content of a response and then writing it to a filesystem.

```
with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
    response = get(url) # may take some time
    file.write(response.content)
```

Problem: while the file is "downloading" it is stored elsewhere (I guess in memory or a temporarily splace in the filesystem). That means I have a 0 byte file as long as the request is not (successfully) finished.

Can I solve this problem without using a third party lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming directly to file can be achieved with `requests` and `stream=true`, or see [more useful examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests)

```
with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```